# How to add users/uid/menu in Drupal 8 main navigation

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-8

In GUI of my Drupal 8 site (mi8test/admin/structure/menu/item/1/edit?destination=node), i can't add the edit profile and node/nid profile menu in my dropdown.

When i add user/{user->uid}/edit or user/[user:uid]/edit -> Both does not create link. It throws page not found(404 error) in the page.

Kindly suggest me the solutions and idea for this problem.

[image: Error page in user menus]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Menu Token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) and this link:

```
/user/[current-user:uid]/edit
```